# java.net.SocketException while sending mail through java via gmail smtp server

Tags: java, email, smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send the mail through java code via gmail `smtp` server but facing `java.net.SocketException: Connection Reset`

Following is the code to send mails:-`

```
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("mail.smtp.host",host);  //host is smtp.gmail.com
  if(host.equalsIgnoreCase("smtp.gmail.com"))
  {
      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port",port);
      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
              "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
      props.put("mail.smtp.port",port);//port is 465

  }
  else
  {
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
  }
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
          return new PasswordAuthentication(uname,pwd);
      }
  });

      try {

          session.setDebug(true);
          MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

          message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(uname));

          message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(toMail));

          message.setSubject(NewFolderName);
          System.out.println("Composing message body.");

          StringBuilder htmlStreamBuilder = new StringBuilder();
          // we create some html string here.....
          Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

          MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
          MimeBodyPart attachmentPart= new MimeBodyPart();              

          DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
          attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
          attachmentPart.setFileName(KMAConstants.TESTNG_ATTACHMENT_FILE);

          htmlPart.setContent(htmlStream, "text/html; charset=utf-8");//we give some html stream here ....


          multipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
          multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);


          message.setContent(multipart);

          Transport.send(message);



      } catch (MessagingException e)
      {

          System.out.println("Issue in message sending, MessagingExceptionn raised.");
          e.printStackTrace();

          throw e;
      }
  }

  `
```

It throws the following error:-
`

> DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
>       DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
>       DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
>       DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
>       DEBUG SMTP: exception reading response, THROW: 
>       java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
>           at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:124)
>           at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
>           at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
>           at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:89)
>           at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2184)
>           at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1939)
>           at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
>           at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:367)
>           at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
>           at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:175)
>           at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
>           at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
>           at com.rsi.kma.common.utils.KmaUtil.sendMailNow(KmaUtil.java:1907)
>           at com.rsi.kma.ui.testconfigureui.FileProcessingTask.call(FileProcessingTask.java:401)
>           at com.rsi.kma.ui.testconfigureui.FileProcessingTask.call(FileProcessingTask.java:1)
>           at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Issue in message sending, MessagingExceptionn raised.

`

An important point to note here is that this code works on some computers.

Please help me out,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some computer in the same network? Same java version?

Comment: Yeah, all computers are on same vlan. All are using same java 8 build 60 version.

Comment: And on those computer this code always work?

Comment: BY Any chance you are behind any proxy?

Comment: @mauros Till some days ago, this code was working on all machines but now it is working on some ...as far as your question is concerned, yes it is working fine on some computers...i've checked it 5-6 times.

Comment: It's hard to guess what's going on. Maybe the antivirus or a firewall are blocking you? Try to disable them. If this does not wor it could be some other program using the port 465.

Comment: You might want to [fix these common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes), then follow these [connection debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

Comment: @mauros you are right , it was kind of firewall that was blocking my requests to smtp server.Thanks Mauros, Sanjeev and Bill for your help.

Comment: Great. I would suggest you to answer your own question and close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Network policies were blocking the request to SMTP server.I contacted my network administrator and he gave me required permissions.Now everything is working fine.